# Why can String not be used in a constraint?

Tags: haskell

How come I can't set a `String` constraint, but a `Num` works just fine?

This works:

```
ltest' :: (Num a) => a -> a
ltest' a = (\b -> b * 2) a
```

This does not:

```
test' :: (String a) => a -> a
test' a = a ++ " good job"
```

Error:

```
• Expecting one fewer argument to ‘String’
  Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘String’ has kind ‘*’
• In the type signature:
    test' :: (String a) => a -> a
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:String) is a type:

```
type String = [Char]
```

[`Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) is a class:

```
class Num a where
    (+), (-), (*)       :: a -> a -> a
    negate              :: a -> a
    abs                 :: a -> a
    signum              :: a -> a
    fromInteger         :: Integer -> a
    negate x            = 0 - x
```

Constraints only involve classes, not types.

Your `ltest'` has a type parameter, `a`.<sup>1</sup> This can be expressed explicitly:

```
ltest' :: forall a. (Num a) => a -> a
```

This means it works with any type `a` that has an instance of the `Num` class.

Your `test'` doesn't need type parameters, because it only works with one type<sup>2</sup> (the argument can only be of type `String`). So it also doesn't need any constraints, because there are no type parameters to constrain.

```
test' :: String -> String
test' a = a ++ " good job"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In other words, `ltest'` has a *polymorphic* type.

<sup>2</sup> In other words, `test'` has a *monomorphic* type.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to make sure you pass only String values as function param like in C for example function x(char a){}

Comment: That is achieved by declaring the type as `String -> String`.

Comment: So there is no way of having something like this (String a) => a -> a ?

Comment: I'm confused - What do you want that to do?

Comment: @vodich No, since `String` is a type, not a constraint on some type.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, cheers!

Comment: @vodich What do you want `String a => a -> a` to mean that is different from what you believe `String -> String` means?

Comment: I guess I thought you can have String x like in Typeclass Num x and then x is used instead of String -> String x -> x. Nevermind I just read a section about types in "Haskell Programming from first principles" so all is clear now